# Why transposing doesn't work (is not working) in quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

For example I have an equation:

$4k^2-24k+0=0$

$\implies 4k^2 = 24k$

$\implies 4 × k × k = 24 × k$

$\implies 4k = 24$

$\implies k = 6$

But it doesn't find $0$ as an answer that quadratic equation method or factorisation method does. Why?

Comment: Is the third step correct if $k = 0$?

Comment: You can't divide by zero which is why this method doesn't reveal that answer, you divide by $k$ so $k \neq 0$ was assumed when you took that step.

Comment: Indeed your third line is true for $n=0$ and $n=6$ but your fourth is only true for $n=6$

Answer (score 4):

Doing the third step ($4k^2 = 24k \implies 4k=24 \ $) you are dividing both sides by k and you can't divide by $0$ so, for this step you are supposing that $k \neq 0$ and you have to check if $k=0$ is a solution.

A better way to solve it is by grouping $4k$, so you get $4k(k-6)=0$ and concluding by this observation: if a product of two real numbers is $0$ then at least one of them must be $0$, so you have $k=0$ and $k=6$ as solutions.

Comment: That's exactly the reason one should never "divide" by an unknown quantity $x$ to simplify because it leads to paradoxes relating to $\dfrac{\text{something}}{0}$.

For example, 
\begin{align}
&x^2 - x = 0\\
&\implies x^2 = x\\
&\implies x = 0.
\end{align}

In the first line, $x=1$ is a root. In the last line, it is not.

Comment: @algevristis dividing by $x$ results in $x = 1$, not $x=0$

Comment: Oh yea, but point still stands. 
$x = 1$ but $x=0$ solved the first one, but not the final one.

Thanks for noticing.